# Creating a table of Hashtags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hashtag

I want to create a table of hashtags that a user can simply click and it adds to a separate submit input. Similarly, if they add a hashtag they no longer want, they can click the hashtag and it goes back into the table.

The table would look like this: [image]

Basically, this would function the same as the "Tags" section on Stack Overflow right before submitting a question.

Any ideas of plugins / code snippets or is hard coding this with HTML / jQuery the only way?

Comment: Can you share what you may have tried?

Comment: [Select2](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)?

Comment: Select2 is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks hjpotter92!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Select2 would do what you're trying to achieve. See this link from JQuery http://plugins.jquery.com/select2/

Comment: I just saw that @hjpotter92 suggested this same method in the comments. Sorry!